# How to increase the id(doc) while inserting data into firestore in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, increment, auto-increment

```
    const userRef = db.collection("criminals").doc(    db.collection("criminals").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {      
      sizeOfCollection=querySnapshot.size+1; 
  })).set({
name:"Manoj",
age:21
})
```

**In the above piece of code, i'm trying to increment doc value. How to increment the doc value like auto increment(+1)**

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please, considering accepting/upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to have a counter of the size of the collection and increment it, you need to use the `querySnapshot()` method differently. It should look something like this.

```
...
const sizeOfCollection=querySnapshot.size();
sizeOfCollection+1;
...
```

Besides that, I would like to add as well, **that you won't need a counter, due to the fact that every time you add a document to your collection, it will increment the size of the collection automatically.**

Let me know if the information helped you!